# How to optimize this query in SqlAlchemy to get the last data?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This query becomes very slow when there is no data that matches the filter, when there is data the query takes 0.1 seconds but when there is no delay approximately 571 seconds. I need to optimize this query and I don't know if SqlAlchemy is doing something strange in the background.

The idea of the query is fetch the last data related with a related id.

```
last_data_query = (
    session.query(
        Variable.id_var.label("id_var"),
        Variable.date.label("date"),
        Variable.value.label("value"),
    )
    .filter(
        Variable.id_var == var_id,
        Variable.date < tsstart_in_milliseconds,
    )
    .order_by(
        sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc(
        Variable.date
        )
    ).limit(1)
)
```

I hope to improve the performance of this query.

Comment: Could you share the DDL for the table and indexes involved, the plain SQL query and the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for this query? (in plain text)

Answer (score 0):

`order_by` is most probably the issues since when there is no data that matches the filter, the database may still need to sort through all the records. (so, one possible optimization is to remove the `order_by` clause and use a subquery to select the maximum date for the specified variable and then filter on that date in the outer query. Thisis much faster.

Try this:

```
max_date_query = (
    session.query(
        sqlalchemy.func.max(Variable.date).label("max_date")
    )
    .filter(
        Variable.id_var == var_id,
        Variable.date < tsstart_in_milliseconds,
    )
)

last_data_query = (
    session.query(
        Variable.id_var.label("id_var"),
        Variable.date.label("date"),
        Variable.value.label("value"),
    )
    .filter(
        Variable.id_var == var_id,
        Variable.date == max_date_query
    ).limit(1)
)
```

Let me know if it reduced the execution time.